# Auto Assign Serial Number to a text on other column in excel

Tags: excel, autorepeat

please see below image to understand what i want to do.

[Excel Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIPbv.png)

John has serial# 1001, when john is repeated on client column, serial# is same as it was on first entry.
How can i automate this process in excel?

Comment: Do you always write the client Name in the same way? which formula you use for the serial number?

Comment: yes i always name in the same way. First i assign a serial number to a client, and then my team calls to clients. When i make a summary it's bit difficult to me recognize the thousands to clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `1001` in A2.  Then in A3 put:

```
=IF(B3<>"",IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A2,MATCH(B3,$B$1:B2,0)),MAX($A$1:A2)+1),"")
```

And copy it down the column.

[image]

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Craner can you please edit this formula e.g i want client first name and last name separate columns. Auto increment will not took place until first name and last name columns are filled by user. Thanks

Comment: can you please take a look on my above comment. Thanks

Comment: New Question = New Post @MuhammadNaeem

Comment: Thanks dear, but it is very difficult me to use technical language to write a typical question like it is. Somehow i will try my best if reader can understand what i want to say. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

use the index/match formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A3,MATCH(B4,$B$1:$B3,0))
```

[image: index match]

Comment: where to paste this formula?